# Make Square Rectangles in a fixed Square Picturebox like a grid

Tags: c#, .net, rectangles, drawrectangle

I am working on a project using c# and visual studio(.NET Framework) in which the user can interact with some square boxes arranged in a grid using a PictureBox. The default size will be 20 x 20
The user can change the number of squares in the PictureBox but the size of the PictureBox should remain the same. I use WinForms.

The code that I have tried by using my logic and some of the internet's, I get it working as a square grid with squares in them, but as I increase the xNum or yNum, the grid starts becoming smaller and smaller. Here is my function which performs the drawing of rectangles:

```
 public Graphics CreateRectangles(int xNum, int yNum, Graphics g)
        {
            rectList.Clear();

            int width = (pictureBox1.Image.Height / xNum) - 1;
            int height = (pictureBox1.Image.Height / yNum) - 1;
            int both = (width + height) / 2;

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
            rect.Size = new Size(both, both);
            for(int x = 0; x < xNum; x++)
            {
                rect.X = x * rect.Width;
                for(int y = 0; y < yNum; y++)
                {
                    rect.Y = y * rect.Height;
                    rectList.Add(rect);
                }
            }
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            foreach (Rectangle rec in rectList)
            {
                Pen p = new Pen(Color.Blue);
                g.DrawRectangle(p, rec);
            }
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Blue), 0, yNum * height, xNum * width, yNum * height);
            return g;
        }
```

I clear the screen whenever I want to draw by

```
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap((Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 8) * 7, (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 8) * 7);
```

Please help me fix the issue so that the size of the square area in the pictureBox1 remains the largest it can be without overlapping other GUI Elements.
Thanks In Advance.

EDIT:
I know that if I have relative sizes then the cell size will go down, but that'
s expected behaviour, But I don't want the whole frame of the table to go down in size, As when I increase the xNum, the size of the outer frame/box should remain same

Comment: Of course the grid cells become smaller and smaller when you increase the number of the cells. If you don't want this behavior, then draw fixed size cells.

Comment: The problem is that the grid cells may decrease but there overall are is also decreasing

Comment: You're leaking Pens as you are not disposing of them.  Either create the pen (outside of the loop since they are all the same) with a `using` block, or switch to the default pen since you aren't specifying a different size with `Pens.Blue`.

Comment: "Please help me fix the issue so that the size of the square area in the pictureBox1 remains the largest it can be without overlapping other GUI Elements."  ...and how are we supposed to know that size without knowing what is on the form and the layout?...